# Authenticating other Users from my App - Tweepy

Tags: python, authentication, twitter, tweepy, twitter-oauth

I've created an app in python to like tweets by hitting the POST endpoint -very simple.

Next I'd like to have an account different than mine able to login and authenticate to use the feature.

I have no clue how to do that and would appreciate any advice
I'm a junior dev, just starting to mess around with an API

for background: I'm going to implement this in flask but for now, just have a python like.py file with basic logic in it for my dev account authentication

```
import tweepy
import config
import time

client = tweepy.Client(
    bearer_token=config.bearer_token,
    consumer_key=config.consumer_key,
    consumer_secret=config.consumer_secret,
    access_token=config.access_token,
    access_token_secret=config.access_token_secret
)


print('Sup Loser, what you wanna like? \n')
search = input('query: ')

query= f'{search} -is:retweet -has:media -is:reply'
response = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=42)

for tweets in response.data:
    id = tweets.id
    print(f"searching '{search}' liking tweet -- ID# {id} -- URL https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/{id}")

    time.sleep(1)
    client.like(id)
```